# Error when Installing Meteor in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, meteor

So I've searched around for a little while but can't seem to find anything relevant to my situation.  I'm trying to install Meteor on Ubuntu (fairly new to Ubuntu) but when I run the curl command I receive the following error message.

```
curl: (35) error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure Installation failed.
```

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and have tried a number of commands to install Meteor including the following.

```
curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh

curl install.meteor.com
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, I had same problem and `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` helped.
No idea what can be the reason though.

Comment: It worked after I ran the update and upgrade.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Run `openssl s_client -connect install.meteor.com:443` and you'll see the certificate chain presented. My OpenSSL refuses to verify that certificate because `verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate`:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect install.meteor.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = PositiveSSL CA 2
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard/CN=*.meteor.com
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=PositiveSSL CA 2
 1 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=PositiveSSL CA 2
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
---
```

Presumably I don't have the `AddTrust External CA Root` installed, and I wouldn't be surprised if you've got the same problem.

`wget(1)` downloaded the script without a single complaint for me. (Which is worrying in its own right. It *should* complain if the CA is not known.)