# curl can't connect to only certain HTTPS hosts

Tags: http, curl, https, meteor, vagrant

I am trying to install Meteor.js on a VM (Ubuntu 12.04) created with Vagrant.

The install should be as simple as:
`curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh`

However this fails with
 `curl: (7) couldn't connect to host`

I have isolated the failure to a request within that shell script to this URL:
`https://warehouse.meteor.com/bootstrap/0.7.0.1/meteor-bootstrap-Linux_i686.tar.gz`

When I changed it to use HTTP instead of HTTPS it works.  However I am running into problems elsewhere where it needs to pull things from `httpS://warehouse.meteor.com/...`

I thought the problem was with https, but if I do:
`curl https://google.com`

I get the page no problem, so what could be the issue?

Comment: Said hosts work for me. However, it would be interesting to know what happens if you run curl with the `--verbose` option.

Comment: ```Downloading Meteor distribution
+ tar -xzf - -C /home/pihentagy/.meteor-install-tmp -o
+ curl -v --progress-bar --fail https://d3sqy0vbqsdhku.cloudfront.net/packages-bootstrap/1.0.3.2/meteor-bootstrap-os.linux.x86_64.tar.gz
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
* Could not resolve host: d3sqy0vbqsdhku.cloudfront.net
* Closing connection 0

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: d3sqy0vbqsdhku.cloudfront.net

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
+ echo Installation failed.
Installation failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

[Per another Ubuntu/Meteor question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679961/error-when-installing-meteor-in-ubuntu), it appears that there's some kind of certificate error (Meteor's SSL CA may not be installed by default in Ubuntu?) that goes away when you:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

For me upgrade didn't solve the problem.

My solution was to download the script from install.meteor.com and replace `TARBALL_URL` from https to http and I ran the script manually.